# WebAssembly Implicit caching doesn't work on Chrome 75

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-devtools, webassembly

I have a working page with wasm that take 5 seconds to compile on `Chrome`. I'm following this article:

https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-75#implicit-caching

about implicit-caching to make the cache work for the second reload. When I reload the page every time it take 5 seconds to compile.

I'm using `WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming` that get a fetch Response.
Using `Chrome DevTool` I can see that the server `return 304` (but the status of the fetch object is `200`)

`wasm` size is 3.5 mega and the server return the correct Content-Type header: `application/wasm`.

When I use tracing

https://v8.dev/blog/wasm-code-caching#tracing

to debug the `V8 behaviour`, I can see that it write the cache `v8.wasm.cachedModule` but never read it. I don't get `v8.wasm.moduleCacheHit` nor `v8.wasm.moduleCacheInvalid`
as every run is a cold run.

Enabling `WebAssembly compiled module cache` has no effect.

```
(async () => {
  const fetchPromise = fetch('mybig.wasm');
  const { instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetchPromise, importObject);
  console.log(instance);
})();
```

I don't get any error and everything work as expected but without caching.

Comment: Have you enabled the cache?.. `about:flags`  -> `WebAssembly compiled module cache`,  without enabling manually I believe it's only 1% of Stable channel atm.

Comment: Enabling `WebAssembly compiled module cache` has no effect.

Comment: Out of curiosity is your assembly more that 128 kB, as currently it won't cache smaller than this.  Also make sure your backend is sending `application/wasm` as it's content type.

Comment: My assembly is 3.5 mega, and yes, the server return `application/wasm`

Comment: Sorry, running out of ideas here.  Everything looks & sounds like it should cache.  A wild stab here, in the network tab in Chrome you have not accidentally hit `disable cache`, does other assets appear to cache OK?..  Only other thing I can think you could try, instead of getting the 304 in the first place, try setting your server headers to long cache times instead and use cache busting for updates.

Comment: If your compiled module is too large, it may fail to be written to the cache,  which is typically around 300 MB on desktop systems. The size limit is 1/8 of this total, so around 37 MB (compiled size). That is increased to up to 1/2 of the cache in M77. I've observed an expansion of up to 7x going from .wasm to compiled, serialized code. The tracing events should have the compiled code size.

Comment: Another thing to double check is the resource URL. It must be identical, including any query suffix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in chrome 75. My compiled webassembly was 46 mega, it write the trace `v8.wasm.cachedModule` but fail to actually add it to cache.
Using `Chrome 77` fix this problem.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=719172#c63